# Why does my C# API work fine on the server but it always fails when I try to call it from any other client machine?

Tags: c#, api

I am having a C# API that takes an Excel sheet (filePath, sheetName) as an input and return the sheet content as the output in JSON form.
The API works fine when I try to test it on my machine that contains windows server 2016 installed on it. But it always fail when I try to send the file path and sheet name from the form.
This is my API Code...

```
public IHttpActionResult GetSheetData(string filePath, string sheetName)
        {
            try
            {
                var connectionString = $@"
                                        Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                                        Data Source={filePath};
                                        Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""";
                using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = $@"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}$]";
                    using (var DRow = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var query = DRow.Cast<DbDataRecord>().Select(row => new
                        {
                            name = row[0],
                            age = row[1],
                            email = row[2]
                        });
                        var JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
                        return Ok(JSON);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { return Ok(HttpStatusCode.NotFound); };
        }
```

The JSON result is returned perfectly when I test the API on the Server, But when I try to test it using this form..
[image]
It always returns 404 (Not Found).

This is my sample excel sheet data.
[image]

Any Ideas?!

Comment: APIs are REST, they are called through http protocol, so you can not use them as simple console application,
What you can do, is to launch your app from localhost and then in your window app, you make calls to it.
Or else, you create a separate Service library and you put your logic, then you reference it in your API and you window app

Comment: @IsmailDiari Hi Ismail, in this case I am calling the API through an Http protocol already. The only purpose of it is to read the excel sheet content and convert it into JSON. and this is already achieved over the server. The problem now is that it always fails when I send the path and the sheet name in the url from the form.

Comment: have you ckecked the url that you send? is it the same as the one you sent through the server?

Comment: Yes Same URL, I checked many times, but let me ask you a question?
Is there any possibility that the API might be not able to access the local files in the client machine? as the file it reads is already exists on the server, so it might be the problem!!

Comment: It depends on the roles given to the user account given to your application pool. but your probem is far away of that, since your recieve 404 status, which mean that your url does not much any end point.

Comment: So let me get that straight: On you client machine you have a file named `d:\users\location\filename.xlsx`. And you send this filename to the server (ie a different machine) and expect the server to be able to access this file you have on your client? How do you think that would work?

Comment: @derpirscher, yes that is the problem I think. Yes I need the server to access that location and read data from this file, is that possible in any mean??

Comment: No generally it's not possible for a machine A to access files on machine B unless there is something like a network drive or something similar.

Comment: @derpirscher So what I understand from your words. Is that I have two solutions. 1- is to upload the whole file to the api and let the api return its data. 2- use another procedure to get this work done.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Maybe you can just do the work locally on the client? But otherwise, yes ,you would have to upload the file you are trying to parse

Comment: What is your API listening to?  If you are listening on localhost or 127.0.0.1 then you will not be able to access it from an external machine.

Comment: @derpirscher What I an trying to is "to pass the file path and the sheet name inside the file to the API and then the API should read the data from that file and return it in JSON format to be displayed on the web page is a grid.

Comment: @DCCoder yes my API is listening to the machine local IP as the API is already published on the machine IIS.

Comment: Then that is your problem.  You need to listen on a wildcard, hostname, the public IP.  127.0.0.1 is a loopback and will only accept connections originating on the same machine.

Comment: Ok, thank you all for your response, really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my Issue, and I wanted to share with you.

The Issue was all about the access rights of the IIS.
When I try to  access a file on my local machine or in the clients machine, the IIS App Pool must have an access rights on that location.
So, I used the following steps.

1. Browse to the folder containing the file -to be read-
2. Right Click the folder and select 'Properties'
3. Under 'Security' Tab, select Edit.
4. In the 'Edit' Window select 'Add' -> 'Advanced' -> Find Now
5. Look up the result names while you find the user related to IIS -[IIS-IUsers]- in my case.
6. allow access controls to the folder -full access- or -Read and Write- etc...

I Hope this is helpful for you.
Thank you all.